# I need to center the Magazine Basic Wordpress them on my page

Tags: wordpress, themes, center

I just installed WP Magazine Basic. The entire theme is left justified. I have been through the editor for an entire already trying to center it. The site is http://www.sportsjabber.net

Something so simply is driving me insane. I can figure all the rest out if I can just center the darn thing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS like this:

```
body {
margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

on style.css line no.33

That will work. Cheers!!!